# Applescript Error: "Can’t make Can’t make some object into type some object."

Tags: applescript

I just updated to Catalina and one of my applescripts no longer works. Wondering if anyone has any ideas as to why? All of the folders selected (single or batch) are on a work server.
The result I get from the Script Editor after selecting a folder is:

> -- 'ascr''err '{ '----':'utxt'("Can’t make Can’t make some object
> into type some object."), 'errn':-1700,
> 'erob':'alis'("file:///System/Volumes/Data/data/ARLSCAN2/DIGI/ORIG/FRETSCHEL/Auto/DONE/F2509")
> }

```
--Script Name:
set ScriptName to "jhoveValidation"

--Define user name
set userName to do shell script "whoami"

--Initalize ErrorCount
set errorCount to 0

--Initalize stampCount
set stampCount to 0

-- BEGIN SCRIPT!

--Option to change location mode
set locationModeChoice to display dialog "Would you like to check a single box folder or batch check a directory of box folders?" buttons ["Exit", "Single", "Batch"] default button 3 with title ScriptName with icon caution
set locationModeChoice to button returned of locationModeChoice

if locationModeChoice = "Exit" then
    return
end if

if locationModeChoice = "Single" then
    set imageDirectory to choose folder with prompt "Select Single Box Folder"
else if locationModeChoice = "Batch" then
    set customFolder to choose folder with prompt "Please select a folder of box folders with standard ICT hierarchy:"
    set masterFolder to customFolder
end if

-- BEGIN PREFLIGHT

--Populates list of files in finder
set progress description to "jhoveValidation"
set progress additional description to "Loading box and file information..."
set progress total steps to -1
delay 1

if locationModeChoice = "Batch" then
    tell application "Finder"
        set masterList to folders in masterFolder
        if (count of items in masterList) is 0 then
            display dialog "ERROR: No files were detected" buttons ["Quit"]
            return
        end if
    end tell
    
else if locationModeChoice = "Single" then
    set masterList to {}
    set masterList to masterList & imageDirectory
end if

-- BEGIN IMAGE PROCESSING

set folderCount to count masterList
set folderCounter to 1

repeat with aFolder in masterList
    set currentWorkingBox to getLastPathItem(aFolder)
    tell application "Finder"
        try
            set inputFolder to (every folder in aFolder whose name begins with "TIFF") as alias
        on error
            display dialog "There was an error finding your TIFF folder for box:
" & currentWorkingBox & "

Please place the images you want to inspect in a completed box folder with a TIFF folder inside." buttons ["Quit"]
            return
        end try
    end tell
    
    set progress description to (currentWorkingBox as text) & ": jhoveValidation - Box " & folderCounter & " of " & folderCount
    set progress additional description to "Loading TIFF files..."
    set progress total steps to -1
    
    tell application "Finder"
        try
            set filesList to files in inputFolder
            set filesCount to count filesList
        on error
            display dialog "There was an error finding your TIFF folder for box:
" & currentWorkingBox & "

Please place the images you want to inspect in a completed box folder with a TIFF folder inside." buttons ["Quit"]
            return
        end try
    end tell
    
    
    --***BEGIN LOOP***
    --Individual file processing begins here
    
    set loggingCounter to 0
    set totalSteps to count filesList
    set progress total steps to totalSteps
    
    repeat with aFile in filesList
        
        set loggingCounter to loggingCounter + 1
        log loggingCounter
        set progress additional description to "Processing file " & loggingCounter & " of " & totalSteps
        set progress completed steps to loggingCounter
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "."
        if (the last text item of (aFile as text) is "tif") then
            tell application "Finder"
                set theFile to aFile as alias
                set theFilePath to POSIX path of theFile
                log theFilePath
            end tell
            do shell script "cd ~/Desktop/jhove; ./jhove -c conf/jhove.conf -l SEVERE -o " & (theFilePath as text) & ".txt -m TIFF-hul " & theFilePath
        else
        end if
    end repeat
    
    set progress additional description to "Processing Results & Generating Reports..."
    set progress total steps to -1
    set currentWorkingFolderPath to POSIX path of (aFolder as alias)
    try
        do shell script "mkdir " & currentWorkingFolderPath & "VALIDATION"
    end try
    do shell script "mv " & currentWorkingFolderPath & "TIFF/*.txt " & currentWorkingFolderPath & "VALIDATION"
    
    do shell script "grep -H 'Status' " & currentWorkingFolderPath & "VALIDATION/*.txt | sed 's/:/,/' > " & currentWorkingFolderPath & "VALIDATION/results.csv"
    
    set theResults to {}
    set theResults to theResults & paragraphs of (do shell script "cat " & currentWorkingFolderPath & "VALIDATION/results.csv")
    set resultsCount to count theResults
    set rejectList to {}
    set reportStatus to "PASS"
    set passCounter to 0
    set failCounter to 0
    repeat with aResult in theResults
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ","
        log text item 2 of aResult
        set thisVar to text item 2 of aResult
        if (text item 2 of aResult as text) = "  Status: Well-Formed and valid" then
            set passCounter to passCounter + 1
            log "PASS"
        else
            set failCounter to failCounter + 1
            set rejectList to rejectList & aResult
            set reportStatus to "FAIL"
            log "FAIL"
        end if
    end repeat
    
    set totalCount to passCounter + failCounter
    if reportStatus = "PASS" then
        do shell script "echo \"All files have passed JHOVE Validation.\" > " & currentWorkingFolderPath & "jhoveReport.txt"
        do shell script "echo \" \" >> " & currentWorkingFolderPath & "jhoveReport.txt"
        do shell script "echo \"" & passCounter & " files were validated.\" >> " & currentWorkingFolderPath & "jhoveReport.txt"
        do shell script "echo \" \" >> " & currentWorkingFolderPath & "jhoveReport.txt"
        do shell script "date >> " & currentWorkingFolderPath & "jhoveReport.txt"
    else
        do shell script "echo \"!!! ATTENTION - some files have failed JHOVE Validation!!! \" > " & currentWorkingFolderPath & "jhoveReport.txt"
        do shell script "echo \"" & passCounter & " files passed.\" >> " & currentWorkingFolderPath & "jhoveReport.txt"
        do shell script "echo \"" & failCounter & " files failed.\" >> " & currentWorkingFolderPath & "jhoveReport.txt"
        do shell script "echo \" \" >> " & currentWorkingFolderPath & "jhoveReport.txt"
        do shell script "echo \"----- \" >> " & currentWorkingFolderPath & "jhoveReport.txt"
        do shell script "echo \"The following have reported failed JHOVE Validation: \" >> " & currentWorkingFolderPath & "jhoveReport.txt"
        repeat with aReject in rejectList
            do shell script "echo \"" & aReject & "\" >> " & currentWorkingFolderPath & "jhoveReport.txt"
        end repeat
        do shell script "echo \" \" >> " & currentWorkingFolderPath & "jhoveReport.txt"
        do shell script "echo \"----- \" >> " & currentWorkingFolderPath & "jhoveReport.txt"
        do shell script "date >> " & currentWorkingFolderPath & "jhoveReport.txt"
    end if
    set folderCounter to folderCounter + 1
end repeat
--***END LOOP***    
-- END SCRIPT


-- Function: Returns the document name without extension (if present)
on getBaseName(fName)
    set baseName to fName
    repeat with idx from 1 to (length of fName)
        if (item idx of fName = ".") then
            set baseName to (items 1 thru (idx - 1) of fName) as string
        end if
    end repeat
    return baseName
end getBaseName

on getLastPathItem(thePathToParse)
    set thePathToParse to (thePathToParse as text)
    set oldDelims to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ":"
    set lastPathLength to the number of text items in thePathToParse
    set lastPathTarget to lastPathLength - 1
    set the lastPathItemItem to text item lastPathTarget of thePathToParse
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldDelims
    return lastPathItemItem
end getLastPathItem

on getLastPathItemFile(thePathToParse)
    set thePathToParse to (thePathToParse as text)
    set oldDelims to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ":"
    set the lastPathItemItem to the last text item of thePathToParse
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldDelims
    return lastPathItemItem
end getLastPathItemFile
```

Comment: I have since tested this with a folder that is local and I can get further but I eventually get the error '"No Java runtime present, requesting install." number 1'.

Comment: Do you have the most current version of Java installed? MacOS stopped packaging it years ago, so you have to download it manually; installing the new OS may have removed or disabled it.

Comment: Hey @TedWrigley! Yes. I am currently running the latest version of Java.